# How to set IAM role for container level access in Mesos

Tags: amazon-ec2, mesos

I am deploying my microservice into an EC2 instance via Mesos.  The problem is I am sharing my EC2 instance with other team's microservices. All these microservices deal with difference S3 buckets and we dont want other guys to have access to our buckets. I need to assign IAM role to my container so that only I can access my S3 bucket via microservices deployed in EC2 instance.
We are not using ECS and we deploy using Mesos. Any input or comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native AWS support for this. In the meantime you can use Lyft's [metadataproxy](https://github.com/lyft/metadataproxy) (see also the [blog post](https://eng.lyft.com/scoping-aws-iam-roles-to-docker-containers-c9c5f8f2f75)).

Quoting the blog:

> We had an idea to build a web service that proxies calls to the metadata service on http://169.254.169.254 and pass through most of the calls to the real metadata service, but capture calls to the IAM endpoints. By capturing the IAM endpoints we can decide which IAM credentials we’ll hand back.
>
> ...
>
> To know which IAM roles should be assumed, the metadataproxy has access to the docker socket. When it gets a request, it looks up the container, based on its request IP, finds that container’s environment variables and uses the value of the IAM_ROLE environment variable as the role to assume. It then uses STS to assume the role, caches the credentials in memory (for further requests) and returns them back to the caller. If the credentials cached in memory are set to expire, the proxy will re-assume the credentials.